# ConcurrentModificationException while calling size() on a sublist

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, exception

I am trying to save a bunch of SQL transaction. I am in a context of ESB routes, transferring from a SQL source to a SQL target, and the order of the SQL transactions is not guaranteed, so you can have a SQL update before the object was inserted.

Due to the architecture, I'm saving those SQL transactions 1000 by 1000 (I'm using a messageQueue). So some of these can fail, and I re-route them in order to retry or reject them. To improve efficiency, I'm willing to improve the older system, where if the 1000 fail, you save 1 by 1, to implements **dichotomia** (if the save fail, you split the list and try again), via **recursivity**. I am also tracking an attribute of my objects, thanks to another list (objectsNo) for further operations.

However I am getting a **ConcurrentModificationException** when in my first recursivity, when calling objectsList.size(). How can I avoid it ? I'm also opened, and would be very thankful to any solutions which would provide another way than dichotomia to improve **efficiency** (and would by such bypass my issue).

> Suppressed: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
>           at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
>           at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1040)
>           at fr.company.project.esbname.mariadb.MariaDbDatabase.saveObjectWithDichotomie(MariaDbDatabase.java:398)
>           at fr.company.project.esbname.mariadb.MariaDbDatabase.saveObjectWithDichotomie(MariaDbDatabase.java:404)
>           at fr.company.project.esbname.mariadb.MariaDbDatabase.saveObject(MariaDbDatabase.java:350)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor324.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:472)
>           at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:291)
>           at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:264)
>           at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:178)
>           at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
>           ... 22 common frames omitted

I tried to understand, but there should not be any mistake. Even if I used recursivity, it stays single-threaded. I considered that the issue could be with hibernate (some requests from the save which failed could stay in the cache, and lock modification), but the issue is with the size, which is on a sublist of the original list.

```
    private List<String> saveObjectWithDichotomie(List<Object> objects,
                                                            List<String> objectsNo,
                                                            Exchange exchange) throws JsonProcessingException {
    try {
        objectRepository.save(objects);

        return objectsNo;
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        if (objects.size() == 1) {
            objectsNo.clear();
            errorProcessor.sendErrorToRejets(objects.get(0), exchange, e);

            return objectsNo;
        } else {
            List<Object> objectsFirstHalf = objects.subList(0, objects.size()/2);
            List<Object> objectsSecondHalf = objects.subList(objects.size()/2, objects.size());

            List<String> objectsNoFirstHalf = objectsNo.subList(0, objectsNo.size()/2);
            List<String> objectsNoSecondHalf = objectsNo.subList(objectsNo.size()/2, objectsNo.size());

            objectsNo.clear();

            objectsNo.addAll(
                    saveObjectWithDichotomie(objects, objectsNoFirstHalf, exchange)
            );
            objectsNo.addAll(
                    saveObjectWithDichotomie(objects, objectsNoSecondHalf, exchange)
            );

            return objectsNo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are altering your List while you remove or add something to it, that is why you get the exception

Comment: You might be right, but I do not understand why, I am merely  calling size on a list, then making a sublist of it. I am neither removing or adding something. I searched for the issues like that before, and I saw answers like yours, but I don't think it's relevant to my issue.

Comment: it seems that this is related to the fact that you use `sublist` which is documented to be backed by this list, so changes in one are reflected into the other and vice-versa, I *think* you should create a new `List` like `List<Object> objectsFirstHalf = new ArrayList<>(objects.subList(0, objects.size()/2));`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I didn't know that sublist was a reference on the source list. I will try your solution. If it works, please consider answering the question so I can accept your answer.

Comment: posted the answer... and you are welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would read the documentation of `sublist` is clearly says:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

That being the reason for your Exception (no need for multiple threads for this to happen). Thus when you create a new List, create it via:

```
List<Object> objectsFirstHalf = new ArrayList<>(objects.subList(0, objects.size()/2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. `ConcurrentModificationException` does not mean that the list was modified by another thread, but that something is trying to access the list in an expected state but it was changed in the meantime.
2. `subList` does not create an actual new list, it creates a view on the original list. That means that you cannot change the original list without making the retrieved sublist invalid.

So,

```
objectsNo.clear();
```

is your problem.

See this MCVE:

```
public class Sublist {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(
                IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        List<String> sublist = list.subList(10, 20);

        // outputs "15"
        System.out.println(sublist.get(5));

        list.clear();

        // throws ConcurrentModificationException
        System.out.println(sublist.get(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you daniu for your answer, especially your exemple which vas very helpful. However I accepted Eugene answer because he was first to answer me in the comments.